# Beautifulsoup split text in tag by <br/>

Tags: python, text, tags, beautifulsoup, newline

Is it possible to split a text from a tag by br tags?

I have this tag contents: `[u'+420 777 593 531', <br/>, u'+420 776 593 531', <br/>, u'+420 775 593 531']`

And I want to get only numbers.
Any advices?

EDIT:

```
[x for x in dt.find_next_sibling('dd').contents if x!=' <br/>']
```

Does not work at all.

Comment: why don't you get the text from the tag?

Comment: No, because when `x` is an element it is not equal to a string.

Answer (score 17):

You need to test for *tags*, which are modelled as `Element` instances. `Element` objects have a `name` attribute, while text elements don't (which are `NavigableText` instances):

```
[x for x in dt.find_next_sibling('dd').contents if getattr(x, 'name', None) != 'br']
```

Since you appear to only have text and `<br />` elements in that `<dd>` element, you may as well just get [all the contained strings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) instead:

```
list(dt.find_next_sibling('dd').stripped_strings)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <dt>Term</dt>
... <dd>
...     +420 777 593 531<br/>
...     +420 776 593 531<br/>
...     +420 775 593 531<br/>
... </dd>
... ''')
>>> dt = soup.dt
>>> [x for x in dt.find_next_sibling('dd').contents if getattr(x, 'name', None) != 'br']
[u'\n    +420 777 593 531', u'\n    +420 776 593 531', u'\n    +420 775 593 531', u'\n']
>>> list(dt.find_next_sibling('dd').stripped_strings)
[u'+420 777 593 531', u'+420 776 593 531', u'+420 775 593 531']
```

Answer (score 12):

Using `get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')` with `str.splitlines`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
<dt>Term</dt>
<dd>
    +420 777 593 531<br/>
    +420 776 593 531<br/>
    +420 775 593 531<br/>
</dd>
''', 'html.parser')
print(soup.dd.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n').splitlines())
# ['+420 777 593 531', '+420 776 593 531', '+420 775 593 531']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tag =  BeautifulSoup('''
<dd>
    +420 777 593 531<br/>
    +420 776 593 531<br/>
    +420 775 593 531<br/>
</dd>
''', 'html.parser')
```

Convert this to a string

`str_tag = str(tag)`

Now split using `<br/>` tag and convert back to BeautifulSoup and extract text from it

```
numbers = [BeautifulSoup(_,'html.parser').text.strip() for _ in str(soup).split('<br/>')]
# output : ['+420 777 593 531', '+420 776 593 531', '+420 775 593 531', '']
```