# how to split html text with br tags

Tags: python, split, beautifulsoup, line, screen-scraping

I want to **scrape** and html page, and I get blocked with `<br>` tags.
I tried to split the html content based on the `<br>` as separator.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ouedkniss.com/telephones'

html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

text_tag = bs.find('span', class_="annonce_get_description", 
itemprop="description")

words = text_tag.text.split('<br/>')
print(words)
```

as you can see in the result nothing happens when i split the text , it stay together ????

> ['Téléphones PortableMémoire : 128 GO Produit neuf jamais utilisé
> ▶️iphone 6s 16go avec chargeur original \r\n.kitmains ,blanc.gold
> .état neuf. libéré official : 33000da \r\n\r\n▶️iphone 6s 32go  avec
> chargeur original \r\n.kitmains ,blanc.gold .état neuf. libéré
> official : 35000da \r\n\r\n▶️iphone 6s 128go avec chargeur original
> \r\n.kitmains ,blanc.gold .ét']

Comment: text doesn't have `'<br/>'` but rather `'\r\n'` - use `split('\r\n')`

Comment: BS removes all tags when you get it as text. You may replace `'<br/>'` with something else (but it can't be `<some_tag>`) before you use `find()` and later use this element to split it.

Comment: What's your expected outcome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beautifulsoup split text in tag by <br/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694558/beautifulsoup-split-text-in-tag-by-br)

Answer (score 4):

BS removes all tags when you get `.text` so there is no `<br>` to split.

You can try `.get_text(separator=...)` to get it and it should add separtors between text from different tags. It should put `separator` instead of `<br>`. And then you can use `split(separator)`

```
words = text_tag.get_text(separator='|', strip=True).split('|')
```

or using more unique separtor if `'|'` is used in text

```
words = text_tag.get_text(separator='|br|', strip=True).split('|br|')
```

but it may put `separator` in place of other tags like `<b>` in `'Mémoire : <b>64 GO</b>'`

---

You can replace all `<br/>` with `separator` in original HTML and then use `split(separator)`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ouedkniss.com/telephones'

html = urlopen(url)
html = html.read()
html = html.replace(b'<br/>', b'|br|')

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

text_tag = bs.find('span', class_="annonce_get_description", 
itemprop="description")

words = text_tag.text.split('|br|')
print(words)
```

---

You can do it only with inner HTML

- get inner html as one string (bytes),
- replace `'<br/>'` with `separator`,
- parse it again,
- get text (already without `find()`)
- `split(separator)`

Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ouedkniss.com/telephones'

html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

text_tag = bs.find('span', class_="annonce_get_description", 
itemprop="description")

inner_html = text_tag.encode_contents()
inner_html = inner_html.replace(b'<br/>', b'|br|')

bs = BeautifulSoup(inner_html, 'html.parser')
words = bs.text.split('|br|')

print(words)
```

Comment: that work very well , but there is a problem with "decode". i tried  utf-8" and it work very well

Comment: I removed `decode()` and use bytes in replace `replace(b'<br/>', b'|br|')`

Comment: just want to know what do exactly html = html.read().decode()

Comment: `html = urlopen(url)` opens connection to server but it doesn't read HTML. `html.read()` reads HTML from server as bytes and `.decode()` converts bytes to unicode string. It seems `BeautifulSoup` can get connection or bytes or string and it will work.

Comment: What a fantastic approach, good job.

Answer (score 2):

the `<br/>` is a html tag, when you used `text_tag.text` you took only the text and not the  html part with the tags

if you want to take the info you could explore more:

```
print(text_tag.contents)
# output:
# ['Smartphones',
# <br/>,
# <b>Double puces</b>,
# <br/>,
# 'Mémoire : 128 GO ',
# <br/>,
# 'Bluetooth Wifi ',
# <b>4G</b>,
# ' ',
# <br/>,
# 'Ecran 5.99 pouces ',
# <br/>,
# 'Etat neuf / Sous emballage ',
# <br/>,
# <span class="annonce_description_preview ">Le smartphone et comme neuf utilisé pour quelque heures. fourni avec incassables original ! merci </span>]
```

also you can try:

```
print(''.join(str(e) for e in text_tag.contents).split('<br/>'))
#output:
# ['Smartphones',
# '<b>Double puces</b>',
# 'Mémoire : 128 GO ',
# 'Bluetooth Wifi <b>4G</b> ',
# 'Ecran 5.99 pouces ',
# 'Etat neuf / Sous emballage ',
# '<span class="annonce_description_preview ">Le smartphone et comme neuf utilisé pour quelque heures. fourni avec incassables original ! merci </span>']
```

or if you want a more nice way:

```
content = ['']

for item in text_tag.contents:
    if hasattr(item, 'text'):
        text = item.text
    else:
        text = str(item)

    if '<br/>' in str(item):
        content.append(text.strip())
    else:
        content[-1] = f'{content[-1]} {text.strip()}'.strip()

print(content)
# output
# ['Smartphones',
# 'Double puces',
# 'Mémoire : 128 GO',
# 'Bluetooth Wifi  4G',
# 'Ecran 5.99 pouces',
# 'Etat neuf / Sous emballage',
# 'Le smartphone et comme neuf utilisé pour quelque heures. fourni avec incassables original ! merci']
```

Comment: i tried to make something similar but it splits line `'Bluetooth Wifi <b>4G</b>'` in two separated elements but there is no `<br>`. It splits on `<b>`

Comment: try ''.join(str(e) for e in text_tag.contents).split('<br/>')

Comment: it resolves problem with splitted elements but now it doesn't remove `<b>` :)

Comment: +1, now it works nice. If you add `.strip()` in `f'{content[-1]} {text.strip()}'.strip()` then it gives all elements stripped.